# $\mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow$ Hom(V,V)

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm trying to prove that scalar multiplication gives rise to the map:

$\pi$ : $\mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow$ Hom(V,V)

Which sends λ to “multiplication by λ”. And that this map is linear.

So far, I have proved that scalar multiplication (part of the vector space structure) is linear, where:

$f(v)_{\lambda}$:= $\lambda v$ $\rightarrow$ $f(v+\alpha v')_{\lambda}$ = $\lambda v$ + $\lambda (\alpha v)$ =  $f(v)_{\lambda}$ +  $\alpha f(v')_{\lambda}$

But I do not understand how scalar multiplication gives rise to the map suggested before.

Note: I understand that Hom(V,V) are all the linear maps from V to V.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How would you define $\pi(\lambda)$?

Comment: $\pi$($\lambda$)($v$) := $\lambda v$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have things a little mixed up, here is what the exercise is asking spelled out:

You have given a map $\pi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \text{Hom}(V,V)$, defined by

$\pi(\lambda) = \lambda I$

where $\lambda I$ is the function that takes a vector and multiplies it by the scalar $\lambda$. First of all, if you haven't proven this in class or other exercises, you should prove that this map i indeed a member of Hom($V,V$).

Next, you need to show that the map $\pi$ is linear. Let us start by showing that it respects scalar multiplication. For this, let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ (here we treat the $a$ as the scalar, and $\lambda$ as the vector). Now you need to show that

$\pi(a\lambda) = a\pi(\lambda)$

that is, that these two functions returns the same value for any $v \in V$. Here you need to use what the function $a\pi(\lambda)$ is defined as.

Next you need to show that it respects vector addition. So let $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$. Now you need to show that

$\pi(\mu + \lambda) = \pi(\mu) + \pi(\lambda)$

the same way as above, and using the definition of $\pi(\mu) + \pi(\lambda)$. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It does make sense. Thank you!